# PHP - SQL Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Fields (
ID INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ForUser VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ForCategory VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
FieldName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Content (
ID INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ForUser VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ForCategory VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ForField VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
FieldContent VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to make SQL Query that list results in HTML Table. As Head Table I want to list FieldName from Fields, and as Table Body I want to list FieldContent from Content. Also in WHERE clause must be ForUser AND  ForCategory... to list Content for each field. I'm tried with SQL Join, but I'm spend 3 hours without success. Can, please, someone write me an example how to display this.

Comment: Then post that wasted three hours code too.

Comment: I don't have any idea anymore... I'searched Google but no results for my problem.

Comment: I would seriously question your data structure, for a start. Why not use Fields.ID as a foreign key in the Content table, rather than repeating the FieldName, ForUser and ForCategory in the Content table (which is what I assume you are doing). It would help if you can provide some sample data in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this request correctly (you're a little light on detail), you will need a use a few components to achieve your goal:

Two sql queries (one for the table header and one for the table body)
Some php or another scripting language to display your results as html.

Your first query will just bring back the field names, filtered by user and category:

```
select ID, FieldName from Fields where ForUser = 'some_user' and ForCategory = 'some_category' order by ID;
```

IN your php or other code, you need to iterate through the results and display each result wrapped in the html tags, eg:

```
echo '<table><tr>';

$fields = @ mysql_query ("select ID, FieldName from Fields where ForUser = 'some_user' and ForCategory = 'some_category' order by ID;", $connection);

while ($fields_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields)) {
        echo '<th>' . $fields_result['FieldName'] . '</th>;
        }

echo '</tr>';
```

Then run a second sql query to bring back the contents:

```
select 
   FieldContent 
from 
   Content c join 

   Fields f on 
    c.ForField = f.FieldName and
    c.ForUser = f.ForUser and
    c.ForCategory = f.For Category
where
    f.ForUser = 'some_user' and 
    f.ForCategory = 'some_category' 

order by ID;
```

And in a similar fashion, iterate through the results in php to build the content rows in the table.

Note that I'm ordering on the PK in the Fields table to ensure that the content comes back in the same order as the fields. This approach might not suffice, you may need to add a "sequence" field if you need a specific field order.

Also note my prevous comment that you would do well to revise your database structure. You don't need to repeat all the fields in the Content table, you can just add a foreign key referencing the ID of the Field record

Comment: Second SQL don't work property. When I run second SQL it brings back only part of all data in FieldContent.

Answer (score 1):

Table join query:

```sql
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.ForUser,
    b.ForUser,
    a.ForCategory,
    b.ForCategory,
    a.FieldName,
    b.ForField,
    b.FieldContent
FROM
    Fields a,
    Content b
WHERE
    a.ForUser = '' AND b.ForCategory = ''
```

Comment: I'm inserted that query and  when I fetch_assoc I'm get FiledName repeating with no end http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-05062015-125209.php I'm fetched only FieldName for test.

Comment: Thanks! It lists FieldName property now but I have another problem now: How to put this data property in HTML Table. I know how to list Table Head, but I have not idea how to list Table Boody with FieldContent Data. Please Help Me. Thanks again!

Comment: There is another problem with Join Query that you posted here. When I fetch $row["FieldContent"]; I'm get "Nema" as result, but in database "Nema" doesn't exist nowhere.  Number of "Nema" results is the same as number of listed FieldName